# using GMaps4JSF with JSF

Tags: google-maps, jsf, jsf-2, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display google map on my application..

For this I am using GMaps4JSF lib of Google Maps.

However I am wondering can i use it with JSF 2.0 (with JSPs).

Few of the documentations says it can easily be integrated with Facelets.

Can anyone please tell me is it possible to use this lib for JSF 2.0 (with JSPs).

If not can anyone please recommend me any other maps lib for JSF 2.0 (with JSPs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the Gmaps4Jsf jars.They are mismatched with the google api version.
The latest version of jar supports google maps api v3 but without any support for JSF2.0 (with JSPs.)